# Checking CAS user in internal database with Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication, cas

I'm writing an Laravel (5.7 with dev-master framework) app for internal use in my school and I'm using their CAS server for authentication, but I want to check if the user is already registered in my own database.

I already implemented CAS login with https://github.com/subfission/cas.

I don't know if I should integrate CAS with the "native" Laravel auth (and I don't even know how to do it) or write a middleware or something like that (don't know how to do it either :P).

*ps: english isn't my native language, so go easy with any writing errors pls*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aright, just checked their [wiki](https://github.com/subfission/cas/wiki/Installation) and damn! It's quiet simple; after installing package you need to add two brand new middlewares to your `app/Http/Kernel.php` at the end of `$routeMiddlewares` property:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
         //snap
        'cas.auth'  => \Subfission\Cas\Middleware\CASAuth::class,
        'cas.guest' => \Subfission\Cas\Middleware\RedirectCASAuthenticated::class,
    ];
```

Good, now run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Subfission\Cas\CasServiceProvider` so `cas.php` config file will be added to `config` folder. open it and enter your school's CAS configs.

Very good, now all you have to do is using `cas.auth` middleware when you need CAS-authentication:

```php
//web.php
Route::get('user/profile','UserController@profile')->middleware('cas.auth');
```

this middleware simply checks if current user is logged in on CAS server (continue to controller) or user is not logged in on CAS server (redirect to CAS server login page & redirect back on authentication successful).

Good Luck.

Comment: this is to implement CAS, right? I already done it (and all the steps you wrote), now i need to check if the user id returned by CAS server is registered on my own database and "truly" auth it in my app (maybe using de native Laravel auth without password someway?)

Comment: Yes it is, and cas authentication is reliable, so obviously you don't want another authentication system on you server, i guess what you want is current user's information and a database of authenticated users on your server. supposing this is what you want, you can achieve it by customizing default `cas.auth` middleware.